# If $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 5 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$, find a non singular matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix} 6 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

> If $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 5 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$, find a non singular matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix} 6 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$.

I let $P=\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$, so that $P^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{bmatrix}$ and I put it in the equation, but as expected, it will get tedious because of two degree terms. I couldn't think of any other method to solve it. I then tried to pre-muliply with $P$ in the equation to get $AP=P\begin{bmatrix} 6 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ and then letting again $P=\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$, but here though I am getting simple linear equations, but they are only two instead of four, namely $5a=2c$ and $b=-d$. So, this too fails.

I wanted to express $P$ solely in terms of $A$, $A^{-1}$ by some kind of manipulation in the original equation but couldn't think of any. I am sure there would exist a simple method for this. So, any hints?

Comment: Do you know how to diagonalize a matrix?

Comment: No, sir. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Your method doesn't "fail", it just offers you many solutions. Choose one of the many and see that it works. (There is not a unique $P$, we can multiply its columns by arbitrary scalars.)

Comment: @ancientmathematician I did that, but the solution I took didn't satisfy the original equation and indeed when I checked the answer, the answer given is unique.

Comment: I don't know why you think it's unique: you can conjugate $P$ by any diagonal matrix.

Comment: @ancientmathematician The answer given is $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 5 &-1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I also point out that your expression for $P^{-1}$ is wrong, you've omitted to divide by $ad-bc$.

Comment: That's my bad. I will correct it.

Comment: Yes that is the obvious solution to choose of your equations $5a=2c, b=-d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1=6$ and $\lambda_2=-1$. This suggests proceeding by diagonalizing $A$. For a $n\times n$ matrix $A$, if one has eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n$ (they don't have to be distinct) with $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, then one has that
$$\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_n \end{bmatrix}=P^{-1}AP,$$
where $P=\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{v}_1 & \mathbf{v}_2 & \cdots & \mathbf{v}_n \end{bmatrix}$ is a matrix consisting of eigenvectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\dots,\mathbf{v}_n$ corresponding to $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n$ respectively.

Hence, for our specific problem, we have that (this is one specific choice of eigenvectors, one could also take any non-zero scalar multiple)
$$\mathbf{v}_1=\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix},\quad \mathbf{v}_2=\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Hence a possible matrix $P$ is given by
$$P=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 5 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

---

Alternatively, proceeding by your method, you obtained the linear system (which was done correctly)
$$\begin{cases} 5a=2c, \\ b=-d, \end{cases}$$
which has infinitely many solutions (it is a consistent linear system of nullity $2$), but if you fix for instance $c=5$ and $d=1$, you will get the same $P$ I have obtained. In fact, you could pick $P$ to be any matrix of the form (you can obtain this by fixing $c=\alpha$ and $d=\beta$)
$$P=\begin{bmatrix} 2\alpha & -\beta \\ 5\alpha & \beta \end{bmatrix},$$
where $\alpha,\beta\neq 0$.

Comment: I think that you should point out that you can have any scalar multiples of these columns, since the OP is clearly confused about the uniqueness point.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I did in my very latest edit.

Comment: I need to read diagonalization of matrix then before I am able to comprehend this solution. Thanks though.

Comment: @projectilemotion : solving $AP=PD$ (where $D$ is the diagonal of eigenvalues, as we have here) is exactly the same as working out the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use  brute force method for a more general answer.
Let $$P=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$$
Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 5 & 4 \end{bmatrix},~~ B=\begin{bmatrix} 6 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Then $$P^{-1}AP=B\implies AP-PB=O \implies \begin{bmatrix} -5a+2c & 2b+2d \\ 5a-2c & 5b+5d \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
$$\implies c=5a/2, d=-b.$$
So, finally there are infinitely many $P$ matrices given as
$$P=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 5a/2 & -b \end{bmatrix}, a,b \ne 0.$$